# How do I use Mechanize to go through each link?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize

Am trying to go through a series of links with a css class title and click those links and then get the product title. But i keep getting the error `undefined method each for #<Mechanize::Page::Link:0x007fbfe2524410> (NoMethodError)`? I Don't understand what am doning wrong?

heres my code:

```
    require 'mechanize'


file = File.new("outputscrape.txt", 'w')

agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
                agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'}


page = agent.get('http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A5%2Cn%3A15377001%2Cn%3A6133979011%2Cn%3A6133980011&bbn=6133979011&ie=UTF8&qid=1412193262&rnid=6133979011')

title_link = page.link_with(:dom_class => "title")

title_link.each do |link|

    link.click 
    file.write(link.at('#productTitle').text.strip)

end
```

Comment: what is the value of `title_link` before the `.each` block?

Comment: am trying to store the links to the title book pages then use each to iterate on them, click them and take out the title of the book.

Comment: before you run `title_link.each` can you add `puts title_link`.  Run the program and tell me what that returns

Comment: I get the name of the first link that goes to the title the book

Comment: basically I want to click all the links of the page and get each title of book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mechanize docs:

> link_with(criteria)
>   Find a single link matching criteria.

You need to use:

> links_with(criteria)
>   Find all links matching criteria.

The object mentioned in your error message, `Page::Link`:

`undefined method each for #<Mechanize::Page::Link:0x007fbfe2524410>
(NoMethodError)`

doesn't sound like more than one thing, does it? More than one thing would be more like Page::Links, or Page::Link::Group, or Page::LinkSet.  You are doing the equivalent of:

```
10.each do |number|
  puts number
end
```

However, numbers do not have an each() method, so that produces the error:

```
undefined method `each' for 10:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Compare that to your error:

```
undefined method each for #<Mechanize::Page::Link:0x007fbfe2524410>
```

On the other hand an Array does have an each() method, so you can do this:

```
[10, 20, 30].each do |number|
  puts number
end
```